# jobsコマンドのzshとbashでの動作の違いについて

Tags: bash, zsh

jobsコマンドを使用する上でzshでの挙動の違いに困っています．具体的には

```
#!/bin/zsh
for i in {1..10}; do
    sleep 1 &
    jobs | wc -l
    jobs
done
```

というのを実行すると，実行中のコマンド（sleep）は増えていくのにwcでカウントされる行数は0のままとなってしまいます．
試しにこれを#!/bin/zshではなく#!/bin/bashにすると期待通りに（wc -lの出力部分が増えていく）動きます．

また，zshの場合でも上記のプログラムを端末上で直接入力した場合であれば，bashのように期待通りに動作することを確認しました．

実行環境は
・OS:Debian (stretch 9.3)
・zsh:5.3.1
・bash:4.4.12
です．

お手数ですが，原因がわかる方がいらっしゃいましたらご回答いただけると幸いです．
それではよろしくお願いします．

Comment: Mac(BSD)でしたら/usr/bin/jobsとzsh組み込みのjobsコマンドとの違いではないですかね？試しにフルパスで/usr/bin/jobsを指定したら挙動が同じになりました。それと`CID=$!; ps xao pid,ppid,pgid,comm | grep $CID` みたいにして確認したら直接叩いた場合は、pgidが毎回異なりました。

Comment: zsh のソースコードをざっと眺めて見たのですが、jobs コマンドは interactive mode でのみ job の表示を行う様です。なので、`zsh -i <script file>' などとすれば期待通りの動作にはなるのですが、、、バックグラウンド実行の処理の際にプロセス番号が表示されてしまいます。

Comment: @KenjiNoguchi  ご回答いただきありがとうございます．Macであれば/usr/bin/jobsというのがあるのですね．こちらの環境（Debian）で確認してみましたが，該当するものは残念ながら見当たりませんでした．あとgpidについての情報ありがとうございます．ちょっとこちらでも調べてみます

Comment: @metropolis     ご回答ありがとうございます．なるほど，zshのjobsコマンドはそのような仕様になっていたのですね．ただ，それだと不思議‌​なのは，問題のスクリプトを実行した際に，‌​jobsの部分は表示される（sleepの‌​プロセスが表示される）ことですね．こちら‌​もinteractive modeでないと表示されないのではないでしょうか．私の手元の環境では，スクリプトで実行した際に，"jobs"では表示が増えていきますが．"jobs | wc -l"で出力が0のままという現象が起きています．今のところ"jobs > $tmp; wc -l $tmp"が期待通りに動作しているので，これで代用しているのですが，それだと"jobs | wc -l"と挙動が違う理由がよくわかりません（どちらも標準出力を使用しているはず）．とりあえずご対応いただきありがとうございます．私の方でも調べてみようと思います．

Comment: 実行環境を見落としておりました、すみません。

Answer (score 3):

詳細はよく読んでいませんが、 `setopt monitor` を実行すると、期待する動作になります。参考: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/227411/157713

```
#!/bin/zsh

setopt monitor

for i in {1..10}; do
    sleep 1 &
    jobs | wc -l
    jobs
done
# => wc の結果はジョブの個数が表示される
```